# How to perform bidirectional IPC using Datagram Sockets

Tags: java, sockets, networking, udp, ipc

I have developed an application that uses bidirectional communication between two in-application programs(processes). I am using DatagramSocket purposely for a reason. In the server side of the application, when I send a DatagramPacket, it is not being received by the client but by the server itself, since the server receives message just after it sends. This is because the client and server have the same host address. The problem would not have occurred if the client and server program were running on a different machine. The client and server program are:

ServerProgram:

```
package Sockets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;

class ServerTask extends Thread {
    private DatagramSocket serverSocket;
    private final int portNumber;

    public ServerTask() throws SocketException {
        portNumber = 1234;
        serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(portNumber);

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true){
            byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[256];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(byteBuffer, byteBuffer.length);
            try {
                serverSocket.receive(packet);
                InetAddress clientAddress = packet.getAddress();
                DatagramPacket packet2 = new DatagramPacket("Hi client".getBytes(),
                        "Hi client".getBytes().length,
                        clientAddress,
                        3444);
                serverSocket.send(packet2);
                Thread.sleep(100);

                System.out.printf("Server received: %s\n", new String(byteBuffer));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("IOException!");
                System.exit(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}

public class UDPEchoServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException{
        ServerTask myServerTask = new ServerTask();
        myServerTask.start();
    }

}
```

Client Program:

```
    package Sockets;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.DatagramPacket;
    import java.net.DatagramSocket;
    import java.net.InetAddress;
    import java.net.SocketException;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;

    public class UDPEchoClient {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException{
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
            try {
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(
                        "Hello server".getBytes(), 
                        "Hello server".getBytes().length, 
                        InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 
                        1234);
                socket.send(packet);
                byte[] byteArray = new byte[256];
                DatagramPacket packet2 = new DatagramPacket(byteArray, byteArray.length);
                socket.receive(packet2);
                String myString = new String(byteArray);
                System.out.println("Client received: " + myString);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                System.err.println("UnknownHostException!");
                System.exit(1);
            } catch (IOException e){
                System.err.println("IOException!");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            socket.close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to create `socket` in client passing port 3444 to the constructor? In the code above there's no port passed to `UDPEchoClient`'s `socket`.

Comment: @hotkey Yes.. thanks.. I by mistake wrote it 3444. I changed 3444 to packet.getPort() and its working fine now... thanks....